Django All-auth return account inactive at the first social login
I have the local account that status is_active = False. Now I would like to set the account activation status True automatically if users login by their social account.
At my code, I have the Django Allauth hook to set the user is_active to True
class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        email = sociallogin.email_addresses[0]
        user = User.objects.get(email=email)
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()

However, at the first time login, it's always tells me that the account is not active.

When login at the second time, users can login as expected, I'm still not figure out why is this happening. please help me with this, thank you.
